# Oracle EBS R12.2.6 - Report builder Version

Tags: oraclereports, oracle-ebs

can we use Report builder 6i for developing RDF reports for Oracle EBS.12.2.6 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, the answer is No. Release 12 of Oracle only supports Developer Suite 10g and above versions. The Metalink Document (Doc ID 444248.1) has a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Use Report builder 6i for developing RDF reports for   EBS RELEASE <= 12.1.3

Use Report builder 10g R2+ for developing RDF reports for   EBS RELEASE >= 12.2.0